# Need to provide inputs to Interactive Shell script from Python

Tags: python, shell

I am trying to automate updating config files of IBM Sterling Connect Direct using Python.

As a part of this config update, I need to run IBM provided script called as `spcli.sh`. 
I am able to tigger this script from python using subprocess however this is interactive script. When this scripts runs it waits for input commands from user at commandline `SPCLI>` such as

`SPCLI>`
`SPCLI> display local node;` or 
`SPCLI> update remotenode name=;` etc.
so How can I pass these commands from python when it prompts and save the output of command in variable ?

Comment: check `pexpect`

Comment: Thanks, I will import pexpect module and try this